# How long does Google save purchase info for in-app purchases

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is it necessary to save a list of historic in-app purchases locally (or on the back-end) or can I rely purely on `BillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync()`?

The premium features are supposed to stay as long as the app exists and never get consumed. I don't want to verify the purchases in any special way.

AFAIK Google Play caches the purchases locally in case there is no internet connection and syncs it with all of the users devices.

**Is there a guarantee from Google that the purchase information is still available on their servers in 5-10 years?**